# Correcting printed items in Python

Tags: python, xml

I'd like to correct a script. But my head is nested. So I'd like to ask SO.

Script is:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
from itertools import groupby

yXML = parse('/root/Desktop/gb/data/yConfig.xml')

servers = []
for AllConfigurations in yXML.getElementsByTagName('AllConfigurations'):
    for DeployConfigurations in AllConfigurations.getElementsByTagName('DeployConfigurations'):
        for Servers in DeployConfigurations.getElementsByTagName('Servers'):
            for Group in Servers.getElementsByTagName('Group'):
                for GApp in Group.getElementsByTagName('GApp'):
                    for Server in Group.getElementsByTagName('Server'):
                        servers.append((Server.getAttribute('name'),
                                Group.getAttribute('name'),
                                Server.getAttribute('ip'),
                                GApp.getAttribute('type')))

def line(machine, group, ip, services):
    return " | ".join([machine.ljust(22), group.ljust(22), ip.ljust(18), services])

print line("Machine", "Group", "IP", "Services")
print line("----------", "----------", "----------", "----------")
for server, services in groupby(sorted(servers), lambda server: server[0:3]):
    print line("- " + server[0], server[1], server[2],
            ", ".join(service[3] for service in set(services)))
```

XML is:

```
<AllConfigurations>
      <DeployConfigurations>
            <Servers>
              <Group id="1" name="The Perfect Life" username="root" password="mypasswd123" state="">
            <GApp id="1" name="JBoss Servers" type="JBoss" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" state="">
                <Server id="1" name="Jboss1" ip="192.168.1.250" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="2" name="Jboss2" ip="192.168.1.251" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="3" name="Jboss3" ip="192.168.1.252" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="4" name="Jboss4" ip="192.168.1.253" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" username="" password="" state="" />
            </GApp>
            <GApp id="2" name="Tomcat Servers" type="Tomcat" path="/root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/" state="">
                <Server id="1" name="Tom1" ip="192.168.1.250" path="/root/Desktop/apachee/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="2" name="Tom2" ip="192.168.1.251" path="/root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="3" name="Tom3" ip="192.168.1.252" path="/root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="4" name="Tom4" ip="192.168.1.111" path="/root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/" username="" password="" state="" />
            </GApp>
          </Group>
        </Servers>
    </DeployConfigurations>
</AllConfigurations>
```

Current output is:

```
Machine                | Group                  | IP                 | Services
----------             | ----------             | ----------         | ----------
- Jboss1               | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.250      | Tomcat, JBoss
- Jboss2               | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.251      | Tomcat, JBoss
- Jboss3               | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.252      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Jboss4               | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.253      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Tom1                 | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.250      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Tom2                 | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.251      | Tomcat, JBoss
- Tom3                 | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.252      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Tom4                 | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.111      | JBoss, Tomcat
```

The issues are:

1- As you see at Tom4 there is no JBoss Server on 192.168.1.111. This server is only for Tomcat. Jboss4 have only JBoss (253), and others (250, 251, 252) have both. Services part is not functional.

2- The IP prints more than one time. I can't handle it...

3- And the Machine column...

They all must be like this:

```
Machine                | Group                  | IP                 | Services
----------             | ----------             | ----------         | ----------
- Jboss1 / Tom1        | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.250      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Jboss2 / Tom2        | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.251      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Jboss3 / Tom3        | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.252      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Jboss4               | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.253      | JBoss
- Tom4                 | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.111      | Tomcat
```

So, what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: You should distil this example down.  Print out your `servers` var after you parse your XML, and then repost the code where you just set `servers=...` and skip the whole XML parsing part, which is not relevant to your question.

Comment: I don't have a clue what are you talking about actually. What if I skip the parsing? Could I print my other 300 servers in an order?

Comment: @nightrider84: Your question seems to be about grouping and processing lists of dicts or something.  I'm telling you to simplify the script you posted here by removing the irrelevant parts so a) people are more likely to help you, and b) the answer is more likely to help somebody in the future.

Comment: @dkamins: I can't simplify it, this is the problem. And yes very similar to grouping and processing lists. All I know is I need to modify somewhere by typing little codes but I can't. I'm stuck.

Comment: @nightrider84: Your deep nested for loop is parsing XML and creating a list of tuples. If you remove that and replace it with a simple assignment of tuples to the `server` variable that still shows your problem when printing them, then it will be easier for YOU as well as other people to help, especially since nobody has your XML file and is unlikely to try to recreate it.  Your problem is in the printing, so the more extraneous code you can get rid of, the easier it will be to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Warning: this answer is **huge***.

You have a bunch of problems in your code.

## `itertools.groupby()` used incorrectly

The most relevant is that you are sorting and grouping your servers using two different key functions. When you group a sequence, it should be ordered by the same key function that will group it. In your case, since you are going to group by IP (which is the third element of the server tuple), your function should be:

```python
def get_ip(server):
    return server[2]
```

Now you even can sort the servers before processing them, for clarity:

```python
sorted_servers = sorted(servers, key=get_ip)
```

The `groupby()` iterator will yield various pairs, consisting by the key and a iterator which yields all results of that key, as you probably already know. Since the key is the IP, I will declare the loop as follows. Note that the function is the same that sorted the servers:

```python
for ip, servers in groupby(sorted_servers, get_ip):
```

## Concatenating the values to form the columns

Inside the loop, what will we do? For each IP, we will get the set of all machines, the set of all groups* and the set of all services associated to the IP. First, we will create the empty sets:

```python
    machine_set = set()
    group_set = set()
    service_set = set()
```

Then, we will iterate over all servers yielded by the iterator returned by `groupby()` for the given IP. For each server, we will add each server info to the corresponding set:

```python
    for machine, group, _, service in servers:
        machine_set.add(machine)
        group_set.add(group)
        service_set.add(service)
```

Made that, we will join the machines, groups and services, each set in one string. Then just pass these values to the `line()` function and print the result:

```python
    machines = " / ".join(machine_set)
    groups = ", ".join(group_set)
    services = ", ".join(service_set)
    print line("- " +  machines, groups, ip, services)
```

## Checkpoint

For clarity, the resulting code follows. You can just replace all the code before the declaration of the `line()` function by the code below:

```python
def get_ip(server):
    return server[2]

sorted_servers = sorted(servers, key=get_ip)

print line("Machine", "Group", "IP", "Services")
print line("----------", "----------", "----------", "----------")

for ip, servers in groupby(sorted_servers, get_ip):
    machine_set = set()
    group_set = set()
    service_set = set()
    for machine, group, _, service in servers:
        machine_set.add(machine)
        group_set.add(group)
        service_set.add(service)

    machines = " / ".join(machine_set)
    groups = ", ".join(group_set)
    services = ", ".join(service_set)
    print line("- " +  machines, groups, ip, services)
```

The printed result is the one below:

```
Machine                | Group                  | IP                 | Services
----------             | ----------             | ----------         | ----------
- Tom4                 | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.111      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Jboss1 / Tom1        | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.250      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Tom2 / Jboss2        | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.251      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Jboss3 / Tom3        | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.252      | JBoss, Tomcat
- Jboss4               | The Perfect Life       | 192.168.1.253      | JBoss, Tomcat
```

## Sorting by the machine names

It is not *exactly* what you asked for: the lines are sorted by IP, not by the machine column. Of course: this is how we sorted the servers before. To sort as you asked, I would propose this solution: just before the `for`, create a list in a variable. Instead of printing the line, append a tuple with the values to this list:

```python
lines = []
for ip, servers in groupby(sorted_servers, get_ip):
    # ... Same stuff here
    machines = " / ".join(machine_set)
    groups = ", ".join(group_set)
    services = ", ".join(service_set)
    # No more "print line("- " +  machines, groups, ip, services)"
    lines.append((machines, groups, ip, services))
```

Then, sort the list by the first item of the tuples (the machine names):

```python
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda l: l[0])
```

Now iterate over all server tuples and print the lines:

```python
for machine, group, ip, service in lines:
    print line(machine, group, ip, service)
```

## Bonus point: removing the looping behemoth

In the beginning of the program, you have not less than *six* nested `for` loops. Man, this is madness (or SPARTAAA, but both are bad ideas). You can easily remove all this nesting this way: retrieve all the `Server` tags directly from the `yXML` object. From each tag, you can get the server name by calling `server.getAttribute('name')`. The `Group` tag is the grandparent of the `Server` tag, so you can get the group name with `server.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('name')`. The IP can be retrieved from the server tag easily: `server.getAttribute('ip')`. And the service name is an attribute in the parent of the server tag, so you can get it this way: `server.parentNode.getAttribute('type')`.

Summing up, you can get all the servers with the rather smaller loop below:

```python
for server in yXML.getElementsByTagName('Server'):
    name = server.getAttribute('name')
    group = server.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('name')
    ip = server.getAttribute('ip')
    service = server.parentNode.getAttribute('type')
    servers.append((name, group, ip, service))
```

Remember the [**Zen of Python**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Flat is better than nested.

## Sorting the machines names

Oh, sure, there is still a problem: the machines names is not well sorted. This is easy to repair, however: just sort the sets. Replace the lines below

```
    machines = " / ".join(machine_set)
    groups = ", ".join(group_set)
    services = ", ".join(service_set)
```

by the lines below:

```
    machines = " / ".join(sorted(machine_set))
    groups = ", ".join(sorted(group_set))
    services = ", ".join(sorted(service_set))
```

In this example, we are sorting all sets, not only the machine names. I bet it is a good choice too.

I know this answer is inappropriately long but I hope to have both solved your problem and clarified a lot of points.

> * It is not needed to even create a set of groups, since your example only shows one group, always. But I will do it for uniformity.

Comment: Its all OK, but Services part is not correct still. Printing JBoss to Tomcat 4...

Comment: @nightrider84 you are right. It is easier to repair. I edited the question with a solution.

Comment: Yes its solved a lot problem @brandizzi but I still can't make the Services part and started to freak out.

Comment: @nightrider84 I would suggest you to post a new question with your new code, the expected result and the actual result. Send us a link and we can see what is the problem in this new phase :)

Comment: You are something else @brandizzi ! I fixed it, everything works fine. I just got fresh air :) Sorry for my mistake.